# Distribution with singularities.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, singularity-theory

I need some help to prove that $f$ defined by  $\langle f,\psi\rangle:= \sum_{n=0} ^\infty
 \psi^{(n)}(n)$ is a distribution which has singularities of infinite
 order. Here $\psi$ is a test function that belongs to $ \mathcal D(\Bbb R)$.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by $\psi^n$? Is it a derivative of order $n$ or a $n$ potency?

Comment: That means nth order derivative of $\psi$.

Comment: What do you mean by "singularities of infinite order"? Do you simply mean that $f$ has infinite order?

Comment: We can define it as: Distribution f has the order of singularity at most k if $\exists C=C(\Omega,f) >0$ s.t. $|<f,\psi>|\le C||\psi ||_{C^k(\Omega)}  \forall \psi\in D(\Bbb R) $

Comment: I changed $<f,\psi>$ to $\langle f,\psi\rangle$.  That is standard usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you the main idea. Then I believe you can deal with the technical details.

You may already suspect that

$$
f=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \delta^{(n)}_n = \mathcal D - \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \delta^{(n)}_n
$$

where the equality and the limit are taken in the sense of distribution. You can verifie that the distribution $S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N} (-1)^n \delta^{(n)}_n$ is well defined and also its limit $f$.

Then, since $\delta^{(n)}_x$ is a distribution of order $n$, you have automatically the wanted result.